# iOS: How to select specific tab in UITabBar and specific row in this tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I'm creating an application with some push notifications. I handle this notifications in my `AppDelegate` (If app has already been lanuched I use `- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {`), if I want to launch my app from push-notification I should use

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (notification)
{
    //Some code
}
```

My push-notifications are called if app receives some new news. In `"Some code"` section I'd like to open the specific tab in my tabbar (by default `TabBarController.selectedIndex` is set to 3). I wish to open the first tab and open newly added last news (tab 1 is the UITableView with some rows).

What should I do? I really don't know what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "setSelectedIndex" method of UITabBarController? to set desired index (tab)? Based on the notification content you are getting.

Comment: and also "- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
" for navigating to the desired cell of tableview.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora `setSelectedIndex` won't work if my app in a minimized state. It works if app has been closed, not minimized. And I'd like to show news details (perform select my row) not scroll to its position.

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelagate DidReceiveRemoteNotification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

    YourTab1ViewController *tab1Controller = (YourTab1ViewController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

    [tab1Controller reloadYourTableViewWithNewData];
}
```

Your Tab1ViewController must include reloadYourTableViewWithNewData method.This method must get new data and reload your tableview.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. But how to programmatically select some row and add it to current UINavigationController. Each tab has his own navController.

Comment: What does it mean select some row and add it current UINavigationController.

Can you explain a little bit more

Comment: Sorry for my English, the following screenshot will explain more. http://s9.postimg.org/j3jgppcgf/2014_04_03_13_35_25_1.png

Comment: Firstly open tab1ViewController with 
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

and add new row to tableview in Tab1Viewcontroller and
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

New data row will select

Comment: Nothing happens except selecting the 1st tabbar. The row hasn't been selected. The code I've made `UIStoryboard *iPhoneSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    NewsTableViewController *destVC = (NewsTableViewController *)[iPhoneSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsTableViewController"];
    tbc.selectedViewController = [tbc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [destVC.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`